# reflection - physical significance

Tags: reflection

okay as long as physical qualitative analysis is considered i treat reflection occurs due to the following fact:

wave carries energy with it while propagating and when it meets a hard {reflecting } surface through which it cannot pass, hence it reflects {the feasible method to conserve the energy easily} 
in the above reasoning i find certain flaws;

1. energy can be conserved in other ways too( like heat etc.)
2. i think there are certain more vital reasons too ,mine being less important one

okay then what are the real qualitative reasons behind reflection?

most books describe it as "bouncing back of light" which i find somewhat unsatisfactory. isn't it a more mechanistic view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right, it's a lot more complicated than that.  Griffiths' [book on E&M](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0321856562) goes much deeper into the process (mostly in 2nd half of the book).  It has to do with complex E&M processes, based on Maxwell's equations, but Wikipedia has a [nice summary here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_(physics)#Mechanism).

Basically, it's a hard scatter, or absorption and re-emission of light.  It's not easy to describe because the physics are very mathematically intense (though certain gauge theories can simplify it).  What's really interesting is the physics of where it scatters or absorbs (preferred depth for reflection/refraction).  Griffiths covers that really nicely.  It's amazing to see how quickly light reflects from certain materials, etc.

I hope these resources are accessible to you at your local library or school!